# Using pthreads to count number of anchor tags in multiple webpages

Tags: c, multithreading, parsing, pthreads

I am currently working on an assignment which involves threads, and I am not a professional programmer so I am learning how to use threads. My task is to count the number of anchor tags in a web page,I was given a txt file with 100 urls, I reduced to five urls so I can test it,and the objective is to return the number of anchor tags found on each.

My problem is when I run my code without my for loop it works fine, but with a for loop it does not call the function in the thread.

What I want do is use the for loop because I will be looping 100 URLS.

```
void runThreads(int num_urls){

pthread_t threads[100];

for ( x=0; x<num_urls-1; x++ ) 
{

     pthread_create(&threads[x], NULL,(void *) th_run,(void *) &x);

}
```

I get this wrong output when using the for loop...Only the last thread is really working. th_run takes in an int* i , EXP: void th_run( int* i ). How can I fix this race condition?

```
URL=www.google.com
CNT=0
FD=-1
URL=www.facebook.com
CNT=0
FD=-1
URL=www.youtube.com
CNT=9
FD=3
```

Comment: reduce it to 1 URL without creating threads,, does that work (doesn't look like it)? If not, fix your function before worrying about threads. We also don't know what `web_t` is. This is a good `pthread` tutorial: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: I have made edits to reflect what you have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

All threads are getting the same argument, `&t`. By the time the first thread gets a chance to run, the loop is completed, and the value it points to, that is value of `t`, is `num_urls`, so indeed all threads run with the same argument.

Edit: the most straightforward way to fix is to pass not the index (the thread really doesn't care), but an address of data the thread shall work on:

```
    pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL,(void *) th_run, &web_array[t]);
```

It also looks like an out-of-bounds access. Normally, `web_array[num_urls]` should not be valid, but it hard to say for sure without seeing `read_url_file` code (it has `while (!feof())` loop, doesn't it?).

Comment: How should I pass the index to each thread? I check if the last line is NULL.

Comment: I could not delete the above comment, I pressed by mistake.

Comment: OMG, this is annoying, anytways Im getting this error... Number of urls in text file = 1
Created thread number: 0
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
for some reason it is out of bounds when I only using 1 url in a thread.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create an array of data structures of data for each thread before creating any threads and pass in the address of the entry you want that thread to work on to the thread.

```
struct ThreadData {
    vector<string> urls;
    int anchors_found = 0;
};
vector<ThreadData> thread_data(num_threads);
// populate the urls member of each 

for (int x = 0; x < num_threads; ++x) {
    pthread_create(&threads[x], NULL,(void *) th_run,(void *) & thread_data[x]);
}
```

That way the data is stable across thread creation and you don't have to worry about whether a thread starts running before the next one is created.

Then, after you've joined to all the threads, you can just sum up the results from all the threads easily.

Comment: I currently have an array of structs like the one mentioned above. However, when I pass the index in a for loop only the last index of the array is used, please look at my EDIT, I gave more details.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say you pass the *address* of the element you want it to work on.  Updated.

Comment: That would require me to change my struct, and Im not allowed to do that.

Comment: @GuiCosta where does it say that in your question?

Comment: I will edit my question, do you recommend any way to pass the index x? the value of x changes when my threads create.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Declared a new int array, inside my for loop I saved the value of index x into this array, and finally used the values in the array when creating the threads.